# Fazer o mock de um raw_input

Tags: python, mock

Tenhos as seguintes funcoes com raw input, que devem receber uma lista [x,y]

```
def input_origem():
    origem = raw_input("Entre com o valor de x: ")
    origem = eval(origem)
    return origem

def input_saida():
    destino = raw_input("Entre com o valor de y  ")
    destino = eval(destino)
    return destino



def my func(origem, destino):

..
...
code 
..
...

print  myfunc(input_origem(), input_saida())
```

até ai beleza, funciona corretamente, mas nao sei como mockar isso

estava tentando da seguinte maneira:

```
class TEste(base.TestCase):
    @base.TestCase.mock.patch('mypath.input_origem')
    @base.TestCase.mock.patch('mypath.input_saida')
    def test_movimento_cavalo(self, origem_mock, saida_mock):
        origem_mock = self.mock.MagicMock()
        saida_mock = self.mock.MagickMock()
        myfunc(origem_mock, saida_mock)
        myfunc.should.be.equal([1,1])
```

Ele fica pensando, e quando eu cancelo ele rtorna:

> origem = raw_input("Entre com o valor de x: ")
>   KeyboardInterrupt

Comment: Tenta colocar o raw_input em uma função e retornar o raw_input, e assim faz o mock da função wrapper do input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode ser muito tarde, mas se alguém um dia precisar disso, é possível mockar funções built-in:

```py
>>> with mock.patch('__builtin__.raw_input', return_value='abc'):
...     print raw_input('Entre com o valor de x: ')

abc
```